# Update text responses in dialogflow using api

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I want to update (add) responses for a specific intent of a dialogflow agent.
Suppose, there are 3 responses like in the image below, and i want to add 4th response.
[image: response1]

I used `update_intent` method, but was not able to get it done.

```
client = dialogflow.IntentsClient()
intent_name = client.intent_path(project_id, intent_id)
intent = client.get_intent(intent_name)
response_list = ['text response']
text = dialogflow.types.Intent.Message.Text(text=response_list)
message = dialogflow.types.Intent.Message(text=text)
intent.messages.extend([message])
response  = client.update_intent(intent, language_code='en')
```

Using above code, my response is added but as a separate text response.
[image: response2]

How can i add this as a 4th response?

**UPDATE:**
I tried adding text field to the Text object of intent.messages but could not find any method to add the text field.

```
intent.messages[0].text
```

> text: "1st response"
>   text: "2nd response"
>   text: "3rd response"

```
intent.messages[0].text.add()
*** AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'add'
intent.messages[0].text.append()
*** AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'append'
intent.messages[0].text = text
*** TypeError: Can't set composite field
intent.messages[0].Text = ''
*** AttributeError: Assignment not allowed (no field "Text" in protocol message object).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the python client, correct?

The [`intent.messages`](https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gapic/v2/types.html#dialogflow_v2.types.Intent.messages) field contains a collection of rich message objects, including [`Text`](https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gapic/v2/types.html#dialogflow_v2.types.Intent.Message.Text) objects. The [`Text`](https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gapic/v2/types.html#dialogflow_v2.types.Intent.Message.Text) object contains a [`text`](https://dialogflow-python-client-v2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gapic/v2/types.html#dialogflow_v2.types.Intent.Message.Text.text) field which is a collection of text responses.

You're adding a new `Text` object to `intent.messages`, rather than adding a text response to the first `Text` object in the existing `intent.messages` collection.

It sounds like you should be going through `intent.messages` to locate the first `Text` object, then add another text value to the `text` field in that object. Then calling `client.update_intent` with the updates values.

As you note in the comments, you're able to do this with

```
intent.messages[0].text.text.append(response)
```

Comment: i tried that but got error, updating the code and error in question details. basically i am unable to add a text field to the Text object

Comment: `intent.messages[0].text.text.append(response)` did the trick, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Get message and update

```
def update_intent_message(self, project_id, intent_id, message_texts):
    intent_client = dialogflow.IntentsClient()
    intent_name = intent_client.intent_path(project_id, intent_id)
    intent = intent_client.get_intent(name=intent_name)
    if intent.messages:
        message = (intent.messages[0].text.text)
        message.extend(message_texts)
        message_texts = message
    text = dialogflow.Intent.Message.Text(text=message_texts)
    message = dialogflow.Intent.Message(text=text)
    intent.messages = [message]
    response = intent_client.update_intent(intent=intent, language_code='zh-TW')
    print(response)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).